# NetworkManager permissions error on Xenial

Tags: wireless, 16.04, network-manager

So, I screwed up. I was trying to install a VPN addition to NetworkManager and ended up accidentally deleting the entire service (somehow... still not sure how that happened). So I tried to reinstall it from scratch. Warning: I probably did something really boneheaded here--apologies in advance.

I downloaded the tar package and re-built it from scratch. Restarted the computer and looked like it started fine. But then when I tried to connect to wifi, it just hung for a while. Running `service NetworkManager status` I saw:

```
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/local/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2016-09-17 11:34:09 EDT; 31s ago
 Main PID: 2418 (NetworkManager)
   CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
           ├─2418 /usr/local/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
           └─3724 /sbin/dhclient -d -q -sf /usr/local/libexec/nm-dhcp-helper -pf /usr/local/var/run/dhclient-wlp2s0.pid -lf /usr/loc

Sep 17 11:34:26 yichijin-Lemur-Ultra dhclient[3725]: execve (/usr/local/libexec/nm-dhcp-helper, ...): Permission denied
Sep 17 11:34:26 yichijin-Lemur-Ultra dhclient[3724]: DHCPDISCOVER on wlp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xf46a306b)
Sep 17 11:34:26 yichijin-Lemur-Ultra dhclient[3724]: Can't create /usr/local/var/run/dhclient-wlp2s0.pid: Read-only file system
Sep 17 11:34:29 yichijin-Lemur-Ultra dhclient[3724]: DHCPDISCOVER on wlp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4 (xid=0xf46a306b)
Sep 17 11:34:30 yichijin-Lemur-Ultra dhclient[3724]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.146 on wlp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x6b306a
Sep 17 11:34:30 yichijin-Lemur-Ultra dhclient[3724]: DHCPOFFER of 192.168.1.146 from 192.168.1.1
Sep 17 11:34:30 yichijin-Lemur-Ultra dhclient[3724]: DHCPACK of 192.168.1.146 from 192.168.1.1
Sep 17 11:34:30 yichijin-Lemur-Ultra dhclient[3724]: can't create /usr/local/var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-b1cfa2a8-395a-4fe9-af77
Sep 17 11:34:30 yichijin-Lemur-Ultra dhclient[3724]: bound to 192.168.1.146 -- renewal in 39965 seconds.
Sep 17 11:34:30 yichijin-Lemur-Ultra dhclient[3724]: Can't create /usr/local/var/run/dhclient-wlp2s0.pid: Read-only file system
```

Apparently some kind of read-only permissions problem. I'm not sure if I configured something incorrectly when I built the original package, but I tried reinstalling NetworkManager from the .deb package and still had the same issue. So I definitely broke something when I tried to reinstall the first time.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I'm a little in over my head.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe because the NetworkManager.service file for systems contains ProtectSystem=true, which causes systemd to mount /usr as read-only.

When building, you can specify where NetworkManager installs paths like /var/run. See `./configure --help`.

If this is an learning exercise, then good. Otherwise I would just use the packages provided by your distribution... `apt-get install network-manager`.

Comment: Holy... In order to get `gnome-network-displays` working on 1804 LTS, I updated Network Managef from `1.10.6` to `1.15.91` (so that Wifi Direct is merged).  I spent the last four hours troubleshooting the execution tree, using `setcap` and `cat /proc/[pid]/status` and various things to troubleshoot why the child `dhclient` was failing.  This is exactly and totally why.  I simply `./configure && make && make install` and quite clearly need to have assigned the correct path, in my case, to `/run`.  (1/2)

Comment: The syslog entry I was seeing:` dhclient[8114]: can't create /usr/local/var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-266af898-175a-4ef9-b619-1fb92f9ccb83-wlp3s0.lease: Read-only file system`  Setting `ProtectSystem=false` in `/usr/local/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service`, running `systemctl daemon-reload` then cycling NetworkManager solved the problem.  Now to build NetworkManager with `/run` specified and re-enabled `ProtectSystem`.  Thank you!